# Discrepancy in output of post PAR simulation and bit file output

Tags: fpga, xilinx

I am using Xilinx ISE to generate a bit file. I verified the functionality by post synthesis as well as post Place and route simulation . But when same bit file was loaded in FPGA there was a zero stuck output ie no output at all . The FPGA outputwas verified on desktop PC screen using Chip scope pro. Kindly suggest me some ideas about how to deal with this problem.

Shalini

Comment: You prop. did a great job by running your simulations at different levels (RTL, post-synthesis, post-layout).  I would check the difference between the stimuli in real-life and the testbench (clocks frequencies, reset levels, ...) and care (for the moment) about the internal design.

Comment: Can you scope the configuration status pins, or read them from LEDs if wired? Sounds like you are stuck in config.

Comment: If you have verified the LED signal with chipscope, the only thing that can cause this is a problem in your pin placement or IO configuration of your signal. Or it can be a HW issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check the pinout file, make sure your inputs and outputs are where you think they should be.

Check your reset signal is connected, and the right polarity

Check the input clock has a clean waveform at the right frequency.

If it's still not working and you have internal clock multipliers/dividers (DCMs/PLLs), remove them and reduce your logic to something simple with a single clock just to get things going and build it back up from there.